# I can't make a matching constructor without violating c++ extension rules

Tags: c++, g++

I have a classes called **TeamLeader**, **ProductionWorker** and **Employee**

**ProductionWorker** extends class **Employee**.

**TeamLeader** extends **ProductionWorker**.
The constructor in question is as follows:

```
TeamLeader :: TeamLeader(int trainingHoursCompleted, int shift, double hourlyPayRate) : ProductionWorker(shift, hourlyPayRate){
    monthlyBonus = 1000;
    requiredTrainingHours = 20;
    this->trainingHoursCompleted = trainingHoursCompleted;
}
```

**The error reads as follows**: *no matching constructor for initialization of
      'ProductionWorker'*

*...shift, double hourlyPayRate) : ProductionWorker(shift, hourlyPayRate)*.

The constructors I have in class **ProductionWorker** are as follows:

```
ProductionWorker :: ProductionWorker() : Employee(){
    shift = 0;
    hourlyPayRate = 0;
}

ProductionWorker :: ProductionWorker(int shift, double hourlyPayRate, string employeeName, string hireDate, int employeeNumber) : Employee(employeeName, hireDate, employeeNumber) {
    this->shift = shift;
    this->hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
}
```

If I add the "missing" arguments to the **TeamLeader** constructor in question like so

```
    TeamLeader :: TeamLeader(int trainingHoursCompleted, int shift, double hourlyPayRate) : ProductionWorker(shift, hourlyPayRate, employeeName, hireDate, employeeNumber){
monthlyBonus = 1000;
requiredTrainingHours = 20;
this->trainingHoursCompleted = trainingHoursCompleted;
```

}

**I get the following error:** *TeamLeader.cpp:23:128: error: 'employeeName' is a private member of 'Employee'*

This error also happens for the other two arguments that aren't accessible to **TeamLeader**

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Because if feels like a never ending circle...

**TeamLeader.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <String>
#include "TeamLeader.h"

using namespace std;



TeamLeader :: TeamLeader() : ProductionWorker(){
    monthlyBonus = 1000;
    requiredTrainingHours = 20;
    trainingHoursCompleted = 0;
}

TeamLeader :: TeamLeader(int trainingHoursCompleted, int shift, double hourlyPayRate) : ProductionWorker(shift, hourlyPayRate){
    monthlyBonus = 1000;
    requiredTrainingHours = 20;
    this->trainingHoursCompleted = trainingHoursCompleted;
}

void TeamLeader :: setTrainingHoursCompleted(int trainingHoursCompleted){
    this->trainingHoursCompleted = trainingHoursCompleted;
}
```

**ProductionWorker.cpp**

```
#include "ProductionWorker.h"

ProductionWorker :: ProductionWorker() : Employee(){
    shift = 0;
    hourlyPayRate = 0;
}

ProductionWorker :: ProductionWorker(int shift, double hourlyPayRate, string employeeName, string hireDate, int employeeNumber) : Employee(employeeName, hireDate, employeeNumber) {
    this->shift = shift;
    this->hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
}


void ProductionWorker :: setShift(int shift){
    this->shift = shift;
}

void ProductionWorker :: setHourlyPayRate(double hourlyPayRate){
    this->hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;
}
```

**Employee.cpp**

```
Employee :: Employee(){
    employeeName = "NO NAME ENTERED";
    hireDate = "NO DATE ENTERED";
    employeeNumber = 0;
}


Employee :: Employee(string employeeName, string hireDate, int employeeNumber){
    this->employeeName = employeeName;
    this->hireDate = hireDate;
    this->employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
}

void Employee :: setEmployeeName(string employeeName){
    this->employeeName = employeeName;
}

void Employee :: setHireDate(string hireDate){
    this->hireDate = hireDate;
}

void Employee :: setEmployeeNumber(int employeeNumber){
    this->employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
}
```

Comment: It's not a circle, it's a tree. Keep adding constructor arguments.

Comment: You're probably misusing classes. A class is not just dumb storage for data. A class should have a specific *purpose*, and the class constructor establishes the class's invariants. Creating mindless data store hierarchies with classes isn't going to be fun, or helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't Employee have a constructor which takes the pay etc? And the derived classes constructors call that one.

Comment: Something's not right in you whole approach. You have ctors with no arguments, so in a sense your code permits the construction of Employees with uninitialized names (or maybe there's a default name, we haven't seen the Employee ctors). Your workaround of initializing `EmployeeName` with its own uninitialized value is... even if it were allowed (which it's not) and even if it weren't *Undefined Behavior* (which it is) it would still be a very bad idea. **What values do you want this new TeamLeader to have?**

Comment: What does the `Employee` default constructor do to `employeeName`, `employeeNumber`, `hireDate`?  It's hard to understand how your class design works because the default constructor for `ProductionWorker` calls the default constructor for `Employee` but it did not supply a value for those variables and so there is no way to set them.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I added the classes to the original text.

Comment: Stop trying to write Java code using C++ syntax.  C++ isn't Java, and doesn't follow Java paradigms.  For starters, C++ class members support *initialization*, but you are using assignment.  99% of the time a C++ constructor body should be empty, and everything should happen in the ctor-initializer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Team Leaders to have a name, etc. then the `TeamLeader` constructor has to accept the name:

```
TeamLeader :: TeamLeader(int trainingHoursCompleted, int shift, double hourlyPayRate, string employeeName, string hireDate, int employeeNumber) 
    : ProductionWorker(shift, hourlyPayRate, employeeName, hireDate, employeeNumber)
    , monthlyBonus(1000), requiredTrainingHours(20)
    , trainingHoursCompleted(trainingHoursCompleted)
{ }
```

Note: it's preferable to use the constructor initializer list, instead of assignment statements inside the class body.

If you want the team leader to not have a name (although I don't see how you will ever set the name in this approach) and have `: ProductionWorker(shift, hourlyPayRate)` work then you will need to add a constructor to `ProductionWorker` that takes two arguments, e.g.:

```
ProductionWorker :: ProductionWorker(int shift, double hourlyPayRate) : 
    shift(shift), hourlyPayRate(hourlyPayRate)
{ }
```

NB. This answer assumes that `shift` and `hourlyPayRate` are member variables of `ProductionWorker`.

If you are using C++11 then you can use *delegating constructors* to avoid having to repeat yourself so much.  Also, look into default arguments.

Comment: I tried adding the *Employee* class arguments, and I got the error  **TeamLeader.cpp:23:128: error: 'employeeName' is a private member of 'Employee'**    **NOTE This error happened for hireDate and employeeNumber as well.**

Comment: @Ein you didn't write exactly what I wrote then